# prevent json_encode adding escape characters

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Is there a solution to prevent json_encode adding escape characters? I am returning a json obj from an ajax request.

Here is what I currently have:

```
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    $inf    =   getimagesize( $file );

    $farr[] = array (
                    "imgurl"    =>  "/".str_replace( "\\" , "/" , str_replace( DOCROOT , "" , $file ) ) ,
                    "width"     =>  $inf[0] ,
                    "height"    =>  $inf[1]
                    );
}
$t  =   json_encode( $farr );
```

which delivers:

```
[
{\"imgurl\":\"\\\/_assets\\\/portfolio\\\/96\\\/full.png\",\"width\":580,\"height\":384},
{\"imgurl\":\"\\\/_assets\\\/portfolio\\\/95\\\/full.png\",\"width\":580,\"height\":452},
{\"imgurl\":\"\\\/_assets\\\/portfolio\\\/94\\\/full.png\",\"width\":580,\"height\":384}
]
```

but I need:

```
[
{imgurl:"/_assets/portfolio/96/full.png",width:580,height:384},
{imgurl:"/_assets/portfolio/95/full.png",width:580,height:452},
{imgurl:"/_assets/portfolio/94/full.png",width:580,height:384}
]
```

having the imgurl width and height indexes quoted is causing the rest of my javascript to break

not having much luck so any tips very much welcome...

Comment: `json_encode()` does the right thing. This means you must be doing something wrong. Please show the code that breaks.

Comment: The output you want is a Javascript expression, not a JSON serialization. There is however one round of addslashes too much in your output, and json_encode doesn't do this.

Comment: the jquery is http://pastie.org/1927196 the error occurs on .attr('src', json[i][indx]) which is undefined...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the code you have in your question and var_dumping it, I get the following: `string(40) "[{"imgurl":"\/bla"},{"imgurl":"\/blub"}]"`

Only if I double the json_encode like `$t = json_encode(json_encode($farr));` I get the same result as you - so there must be a second json_encode somewhere…

Comment: D'oh - was encoding in the method which returns result to ajaxs script which inturn json_encodes results.... Should a rubber duck debugged that one - srry peeps... ;P

Comment: the essential part "Only if I double the json_encode"

Comment: Forward slashes in urls will still get escaped, but you can use a FLAG to prevent those, like: json_encode( $response, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES )